# Правильное употребление местоимений

Tags: грамотная-речь, местоимения

Недавние вопросы про *Сказку о золотом петушке* напомнили мне об одной заковырке. У Пушкина написано:

> Царь скопца благодарит,
>   Горы золота сулит.
>   «За такое одолженье, —
>   Говорит он в восхищенье, —
>   Волю первую твою
>   Я исполню, **как мою**».

Когда мои младшие брат и сестра были маленькими, они постоянно забывали про слово "свой". Он ест *свой* завтрак, а не *его* завтрак. Я убираюсь в *своей* комнате, не в *моей*. Я их постоянно поправляла.

Но, прочитав недавно эту последнею фразу, я поняла, что я бы её тоже поправила, если бы они её произнесли!!! Я ориентируюсь в грамоте больше на слух, и мне это "мою" режет ухо. Я чувствую, что можно извернуться и допустить его здесь, но если бы я просто сказала это предложение, то не задумываясь сказала бы "свою".

Я интуицией понимаю, какое слово правильное, но объяснить алгоритм не могу и не могу объяснить, почему мне так хочется видеть "свою" в реплике Дадона. Скажите, пожалуйста, в каких случаях надо использовать СВОЙ / СЕБЕ, а в каких - МОЙ / МНЕ (или твой / ваш / его / и т. д.)? Есть ли чёткое правило на этот счёт? И как легче объяснить детям разницу, кроме как на примерах?

Спасибо!

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ: в конце сказки, мудрец говорит:

> — Царь! — ответствует мудрец, —
>   Разочтемся наконец.
>   Помнишь? за мою услугу
>   Обещался мне, как другу,
>   Волю первую мою
>   Ты исполнить, как свою.

Это так, для сравнения.

Comment: Мне  тоже  больше  нравится  так,  как  в  конце  сказки.  Хотя  и  как  первом  случае  тоже  можно.  Там  пара:  твою  как  мою.  Можно  сказать  твою  как  свою.  Речь  от  первого  лица -  смысл  не  меняется.  Во  втором  случае  парой  к  "свою"  может  выступить  "твою",  но  тогда  звучит  как-то  шероховато.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот ответ Грамоты.ру на похожий вопрос:

[вместо | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%E2%EC%E5%F1%F2%EE)

Когда говорится о предмете, лице или свойстве, качестве, принадлежащем производителю действия (субъекту личного глагола), вместо притяжательных местоимений 1-го и 2-го лица (т. е. вместо местоимений мой, твой, наш, ваш – Прим. Грамоты) предпочтительнее употреблять местоимение свой: Я иду к своему брату (т. е. к моему брату), ты идешь к своему брату (т. е. к твоему брату).

Однако при желании усилить эмоциональность высказывания, а также при подчеркивании принадлежности предмета, лица, свойства, черты характера кому-либо (в том числе и говорящему) или личной причастности того, о ком идет речь, к чему-либо предпочтительно употребление местоимений мой, твой, наш, ваш: Я дочь мою мнил осчастливить браком (Пушкин) — упор на МОЮ, ЛЮБИМУЮ; И вы не смоете всей вашей черной кровью Поэта праведную кровь (Лермонтов).

Говоря о вариантном употреблении местоимения свой и притяжательных местоимений мой, твой, наш, ваш, профессор А. М. Пешковский отметил: «У Лермонтова противопоставление всей вашей черной кровью поэта праведную кровь выходит сильнее, чем если бы было сказано: всей своей черной кровью». Главное не то, что кровь принадлежит "вам", а личность этих "вы", заклеймённая позором убийства.

Вторя профессору, можно сказать, что пушкинское

"...Волю первую твою

Я исполню, как мою»

звучит более эмоционально. Это стилизация под речь правителя, он хочет сделать акцент не на ПРИНАДЛЕЖНОСТИ воли ему, а о ЗНАЧИМОСТИ своего Я.

"Волю первую мою

Ты исполнить, как свою." - это уже упор на принадлежности, раз твоя, то и исполняй.

Comment: ВСЕЙ ВАШЕЙ ЧЕРНОЙ КРОВЬЮ  , а не ВСЕЙ СВОЕЙ ЧЕРНОЙ КРОВЬЮ  это диктуется просто размером стихосложения . И никакая особая философия здесь не требуется .

Comment: Во-первых, это Вы профессору Пешковскому скажите, а во-вторых, НАСТОЯЩИЙ ПОЭТ, а не рифмоплёт всегда найдёт нужную комбинацию слов, чтоб форма была едина с содержанием,размер ему ничего не диктует, во имя размера содержание портить не будет, всё поменяет, на то он и ПОЭТ.

Answer (score 3):

Хотел просто комментарий-замечание написать, но там как-то тесно.

Для начала.
Простите, но название настолько далеко вопроса... Поменяли бы на что-нить более соответствующее.

Насчет алгоритма. Алгоритм чего? Использования слова *свой* взамен *мой, твой, ваш*? Ну он понятен, *свой* можно использовать в тех случаях, когда он относится к последнему упомянутому субъекту действия.
Или все-таки интересует, когда такая замена обязательна? Почти никогда.  Если только стилистика не требует подчеркнуть именно принадлежность *свой*: *не суйся не в свое дело*. Т.е. когда антонимом *свой* будет *чужой* - использование *свой* взамен *мой-твой-наш* необходимо, иначе большого смысла в такой замене нет.

Или вы хотите поправить детей, которые что-то там "забывают"? Знаете, я не вижу большого смысла, чтобы подобно англичанам пихать "свой", "мой", "твой" когда надо и не надо.
Применительно к завтраку - не нужно там "свой", дети правы. А еще лучше говорить не "ем завтрак", а *завтракаю*.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример, когда замена влияет на смысл высказывания:

Мне нужны мои деньги = верни деньги, (в конкретном количестве) которые я тебе занял. Верни!

Мне нужны свои деньги = спасибо за предложение, но я хочу зарабатывать сам.

У меня больше нет моих денег = у меня больше нет той самой суммы. Меня обокрали.

У меня больше нет своих денег = у меня больше нет собственного финансового источника. Я живу на деньги брата.

Вопрос действительно серьёзный, нужно подумать, однако в большинстве случаев, если действие, описываемое в сказуемом, совершается тем же объектом, на который ссылается определитель ("свой" в данном случае — определитель, а не местоимение), то используется именно "свой".

Пример:

Скажи Максиму, чтобы заправил свою постель.
(действие совершается Максимом, и постель принадлежит Максиму).

Принеси мне свой дневник.
(Действие совершаешь ты; дневник также принадлежит тебе).

Надеюсь, помог.

Comment: Занимают деньги не кому-то, а **у кого-то.** Первое употребление ошибочно.

Comment: Обоснуйте, пожалуйста, свой комментарий (аргументы "я так не говорю" - не принимаются:)) Занять деньги можно как у кого-то, так и кому-то.

Comment: Такого значения нет в словарях. Только на жаргоне, что совсем не литературный язык.

Comment: Во-первых, лексема попадает в словарь с большой задержкой (она не появляется магическим образом в "словаре" когда кто-то в мире впервые её произносит), а значит многих общепринятых слов там может не быть. Во-вторых, есть разница между прескриптивистским и дескриптивистским подходом к аспектам языка (раз уж Вы берёте на себя ответственность судить об ошибочности/правильности, уверен, Вы знакомы с этими понятиями, ну а если нет - почитайте книгу Стивена Пинкера "язык как инстинкт"). Если данное значение придаётся данному слову значительным количеством носителей - оно становится "нормальным".

Comment: В-третьих, использование данного слова в указанном мной примере нисколько не препятствует его пониманию, и выбрал я его по причинам, указанным выше. В-четвёртых, термин "жаргон" использован Вами ошибочно, поскольку конструкция "занять что-то кому-то", не является атрибутом какой-либо социальной группы. В-пятых, не "на жаргоне", а "в жаргоне" (нет В! словарях, только В! жаргоне).

Comment: Я хотел сказать, что на жаргоне так только могут сказать.